How to handle pyodbc connection errors in the middle of a transaction?
I am currently writing a python script for a cron job that runs weekly. This script connects to a SQL Server db through pyodbc. There are reads and writes (inserts, deletes, and updates). All writes will be in the same SQL transaction using the same pyodbc cursor. This is because if there are any high level errors, I do not want half of the writes to be committed and the other half not as I will have to manually restore the db to the previous state. I would prefer to have the db be the same before each run as there is no way to really resume the job halfway through. If certain records are inserted or updated and other records are not, this causes problems with the job and the db data.
If any high level errors are bubbled up, I will perform a cursor.rollback(). If there are no errors, I will perform a cursor.commit() at the end of the script before closing the db connection.
These are some of the errors I was getting:
('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x274C (10060) (SQLExecDirectW)')
('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (-2147467259) (SQLEndTran)')

I tried catching the error in a while loop with a retry flag and reconnecting to the SQL Server but this would throw away the changes in the previous transaction that were not committed. At this point, I would basically have to restart the whole job anyways.
Some questions I had:
Is there anyway to create a cursor and continue the previous transaction that I disconnected in the middle of?
How should I be handling network errors in the middle of a SQL transaction before the transaction is complete?
Should I just be committing each write after it executes and refactor the job to be able to resume if it fails at any point during inserts? I could reconnect to the SQL Server here upon connection issues since there would be no transactions. However, I'm not sure how feasible this is or if its even better than just running the whole job again upon failure...
Any guidance here would be great as I couldn't find much about this online.

How bad is your connection, if you're sitting on some WAN in the middle of red sea, perhaps you can move the python logic into some job that can be run on the server itself. You could stage the data into some semitemporary tables and then run the code that makes actual changes on the server as well


Is there anyway to create a cursor and continue the previous transaction that I disconnected in the middle of?

No. Transactions are rolled back when a connection is killed.

How should I be handling network errors in the middle of a SQL transaction before the transaction is complete?

Retry the whole transaction on intermittent errors like a network failure.
